# Отобразить 3D карту libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, 3d

Мне нужно отобразить `3d` карту из фрагментов карты, и я думаю, что нужно сначала нарисовать сетку, чтоб потом в каждой ячейке отобразить фрагмент карты, ибо в дальнейшем хочу сделать сцену драки как в "Героях" - как правильно сделать, подскажите пожалуйста?